# tfs express 2012 on windows 7 home: authentication

Tags: windows, authentication, iis-7.5

I wanted to try team foundation server, so I searched it on microsoft, found tfs express 2012, and installed it on a notebook with windows 7 home premium.

The installation was successfull, but when I followed the procedure for creating a new project it asked for a login. I didn't knew what user/pass to use, I tried some, didn't work.

I tried to create a new user (both in windows and in tfs); didn't work.

Apparently all boils down to a feature of IIS, "Windows Authentication", which this windows can't have.

So the question is:

- did really microsoft made a piece of... software that can't work?
- is there another way to authenticate?

I tried to login in tfs and the DefaultCollection with chrome and ie, no success either.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like Windows 7 Home, is not suitable for running TFS Express as it depends on the features of IIS that don't work in Home edition. There is nothing explicit in the System Requirements about editions, but if you are saying the Windows Authentication feature of IIS doesn't work on Home edition, then I guess it won't work. TFS on-premise only uses IIS Windows Authentication.

If you want to try out TFS, why not try [Visual Studio Online](http://VisualStudio.com), this is TFS 2013 plus some updates that will appear in the on-premise version later. It can be used for Free for a team of up to 5 developers.

Comment: But in fact the problem is this: why they let you install tfs on windows home? Why don't you get at least a warning?!
Regarding visual studio online, I already created an account for it (trying to see if it was an online editor, which is not), but I would have liked seeing it working in local.

Comment: You can only use it to edit azure websites, at the moment, other project types will arrive later, lookup "Monaco". As for the installation problem, I think someone from the TFS product team would be best placed to comment.